# how to use JAR utility to compress file as .par

Tags: file, compression

I want to compress a file as ".par" like (.rar) using C#(windows).Can any one help me.I came to know that we can use JAR utility to compress file.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the JAR utility only supports jar files (which are really just zip files). You need to use another program for .par archives.

Comment: Hi 

Thank you for your reply.Can you tell me what I need to use.

Thanks